# How to make a rest request in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following cURL request that I want to make in PL/SQL :

```
curl -i 
-H « Authorization: AUTH xxxx:1539335594582:1:HMAC » 
-X GET http://example.com/api/accounts
```

I tried the following code. It's not working (I'm getting a server error : Your browser sent a request that we could not understand.) and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly in PL/SQL :

```
URL varchar2(250);
Header varchar2(32000);
Response varchar2(32000);        

URL := 'http://example.com/api/accounts';
Header := 'Authorization: AUTH xxxx:1539335594582:1:HMAC';
Response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => URL || '?' || Header, p_http_method => 'GET');
```

can any one help please ?

Thanks
Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP headers cannot be concatenated into the URL like that. You need to set the headers before calling `make_rest_request`, e.g.

```
declare
  URL varchar2(250);
  Response varchar2(32000);        
begin
  URL := 'http://example.com/api/accounts';
  apex_web_service.g_request_headers.delete();
  apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Authorization';
  apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'AUTH xxxx:1539335594582:1:HMAC';
  Response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => URL, p_http_method => 'GET');  
end;
```